# Is it possible to update blob content in GCS?

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage

I would like to write a file to GCS bucket, and if it exists just overwrite it.
The python [docs](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-storage/) show it's possible to overwrite the content of a blob using `blob.upload_from_string('New contents!')`.

For Java I only found delete/create (update just updates the metadata).
So my code currently do this:

```java
  public boolean doesObjectExist(String bucketName, String objectName) {
    Blob object = storage.get(bucketName, objectName);
    return object != null;
  }

  public void uploadObject(String bucketName, String objectName, String content) {
    BlobId blobId = BlobId.of(bucketName, objectName);
    BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(blobId).setContentType("text/plain").build();
    if (doesObjectExist(bucketName, objectName)){
      storage.delete(bucketName, objectName);
    }
    storage.create(blobInfo, content.getBytes(UTF_8));
  }
```

Is there something overwrite via the [Java API](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-storage/latest/index.html)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't update the Blob content (even in Python!). You can only create, delete, read. You can't move, you can't rename. These 2 operations perform a create (with the new name/destination) and a delete (the old name).

So now, how you overwrite the existing content: simply write the content. If it exists, it will be replaced. If you have activated the [versioning on the bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-versioning), the previous version is kept as noncurrent version, and the uploaded content is served as live version.

Comment: is it possible to update like mentioned in below question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67128861/adding-carriage-return-to-every-line-in-a-csv-file-stored-in-a-gcs-bucket

Comment: I answered it. It's not possible by design, you should have an issue somewhere!